# The correct way to organize imports in build.gradle Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

PLease advise me the best way to add new imports to the project in build.gradle Android?
On various projects I have seen different approaches, for example:

**with comments**

```
    //navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    //test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

**or without**

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

**with an explicitly specified version**

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

**using a variable**

```
 def nav_version = "2.4.0"

  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

This is important in my opinion, because every developer visits this file more than once, and therefore I want it to be well *readable*, *convenient*, *optimal*.
What approaches do you use in your projects?
**Thanks** in advance for any feedback!

Comment: there's no best way. you've found various different solutions already and they all work, so it really depends on opinion and what the project has been using, meaning that you can't find an answer, because there is no answer

Comment: `because every developer visits this file more than once` how sure are you about this ? have you ever worked on an old and large system before ? chances are you'll have one look through this to see which dependencies are available to you and that will be all, the odds of you adding in new dependencies will be very rare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally depend on you how easily you can understand and other developer too.

> with comments

as you can see with comments every developer can easily understand which library for what and also very easy for finding specific library in bunch of libraries that's why in my personal opinion i'm always prefer with comments.

```
//navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

//test
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

second is

> using a variable

```
def nav_version = "2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

and in this my personal opinion is always use with variable because it can easily change of version for group of same version libraries as you can see once you change **nav_version** then group of navigation libraries version change and it's very helpful while updating version, you will never got version related issue.

Here what I'm using approaches is

```
//Paging
def paging_version = "3.1.0"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"

//Dagger Hilt
def hilt_version = "2.38.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

//Glide
def glide_version = "4.12.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
```

Comment: do you really feel like those comments do anything useful ? using `//Glide` and then having glide libraries really doesn't help anyone understand what the library does, so your comments are a bit pointless here. if you're going to open this file to change some dependencies, chances are you need to already know which dependencies to change or what you'll be doing, so `//Dagger Hilt` and `//Glide` are useless, `//Paging` is also quite obvious looking at `androidx.paging:paging....`

Comment: what if in your gradle file have more than 30 dependencies ? It will really easy for finding any library and as i said it's my personal opinion i'm using this and it's helping me alot.